# iOS scroll to out of view textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, forms, uitableview, keyboard

I have problem with a long form in iOS. The form itself is done with a static table view. For the form I needed a toolbar with prev/next and done. In this project I added [BSKeyboardControls](http://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls), and I've allready done it myself in another project.

The toolbar works fine except when the next or previous textField/textView is out of sight. Then the focus on the former textField won't change and I'm still typing in this text field. When I now scroll manually and the targeted next textfield appears it magically becomes the first responder. This is of course not the expected behabier.

So I figured out I would have to scroll the table view to the respective fields before trying to set them as first responder. But I connot get this done.

I've tried to this with indexPathes

```
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)textField.superview.superview];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPat:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Although the super-superview is a valid (and the right) table cell, the path returned is nil. I also tried some variations

```
CGPoint point = [self.tableView convertPoint:textField.frame.origin toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
```

and other variations with rects and indexPathsForRowsInRect.

The only way is to manually keep track of the textFields cell indexPaths, but that is no suitable solution in this case.

Anybody has an idea of how to achieve scrolling to an out of sight textField in a tableView?

Edit:

As Justin Paulson requested the code of keyboardControlsPreviousNextPressed:

```
- (void)keyboardControlsPreviousNextPressed:(BSKeyboardControls *)controls withDirection:(KeyboardControlsDirection)direction andActiveTextField:(id)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)((UIView *)textField).superview.superview];
    NSLog(@"path %@ for cell %@", path, ((UIView *)textField).superview.superview);
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

As I said according to the output of the log the path is nil, whereas the super-superview is the rught table view cell

Comment: Do you use UIViewController or UITableViewController as the base of your VC class? One of the advantages of using UITableViewController is that when you assign a UITextField for example to become the first responder, the UITableViewController will automatically scroll so that the field is visible (thus not below the keyboard for example)

Comment: What does your code look like for this delegate function : `keyboardControlsPreviousNextPressed:withDirection:andActiveTextField:`?

Comment: thanks for the fast responses. @Ladislav Im using UITableViewController but it does not automatically scroll.

Comment: @Justin Paulson I'll edit the question and paste the code.

Comment: Why not just have all the UITextFields saved in an NSArray, so that when Next is clicked you just find the appropriate UITextField and let him become first responder...

Comment: Have you tried changing your code in the `keyboardControlsPreviousNext...` to just say `[textField becomeFirstResponder];`, because the `UITableViewController` should scroll it for you.

Comment: Isn't working either. If the textfield is not visible: same problem. I've done that in another project and had to manually enter the index paths for every textfield to be able to jump to that row before becoming first responder.

Comment: @JustinPaulson: it should? Because i tried and it doesn't. In fact i tried again just yet.

Comment: How do you create the array of `UITextFields` in the `BSKeyboardControl`?, also, is the NSLog in `keyboardControlsPreviousNext...` returning the index that it should?

Comment: Well as i said the indexPath is (null) when the textfield is not visible. If it is, it is correct. The fields are created like in the example: self.keyboardControls.textFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.roomField, ..., nil]; where self.***Field is an IBOutlet created with storyboard. The Fields array seems to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help me, i've a solution myself. In my `keyboardControlsPreviousNextPressed` i have now

```
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:((UIView *)textField).superview.superview.frame animated:YES];
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

This solution seems to work quite well. The only problem i've encountered is that *sometimes* the newly focused textField is hidden by the keyboard, so the tableViewController doesn't adjusts itself automatically. You could additionally scroll the row to the top to circumvent this in most cases.

```
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)textField.superview.superview];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```